# How do you map a return value class that includes a protocol implementation on MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to map a return type that has no direct class to something in MonoTouch (something as I'm not sure what the equivalent is).

For example if in btouch I want to bind the resulting type UIView < ProtocolX > defined like so:

- (UIView< ProtocolThing > *)addThing:(Thing *)aThing;

I've done this successfully:

[Export("addThing:")]
UIView AddThing(Thing aThing);

Except I can't then get at the ProtocolThing extensions.  And if I create an intermediate type like UIViewProtocolThing like:

//@interface UIViewProtocolThing : UIView  {
[BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
interface UIViewProtocolThing : ProtocolThing {
...
}

I can use UIViewProtocolThing, but since it creates constructors for UIViewProtocolThing and those constructors don't exist, returning this type fails.

Anyone have a thought about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just fix this on the C# side.  Use `UIView` in the binding.

Then make a class like so:

```
public class ProtocolView : UIView
{
    //Fill out all the constructors
    public ProtocolView() { }

    public ProtocolView(IntPtr handle) : base (handle) { }

    [Export("myExportForProtocolThing:")
    public virtual void MyExportForProtocolThing() { }
}
```

Make sure to implement all methods of the protocol.

You can even put this new class in the binding project if you wish.